# How to get listview selected column & update it & reflect it changes to database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, listview, ms-access-2003

I am doing project in vb.net using ms access
I used listview to display data from table
I want to **display different context menu strip for different column**
I have done it using hard logic to get column number is as follows:

```
 Private Function getClickedColumn(ByVal pListView As ListView, ByVal pMouseX As Integer) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    'Get column rights
    Dim colRights As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim colWidths As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each col As ColumnHeader In pListView.Columns
        colWidths.Add(col.Width)
        Dim colRight As Integer = 0 ' - pListView.Columns.Item(0).Width 'Subtract this if you were collecting lefts instead of rights
        For i As Integer = 0 To colWidths.Count - 1
            colRight += colWidths(i)
        Next
        colRights.Add(colRight)
    Next

    'Which column does the mouse X fall inside?
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
    For Each colRight As Integer In colRights
        If pMouseX <= colRight Then
            result = colIndex
            Exit For
        End If
        colIndex += 1
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

**Also i want to edit any cell of the listview & update its result to database .
How can i do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the DataGrid instead, which will allow editing, value checks, knowing the column, ...